# Kids trailer (Weber hitch) on a folding bike (Tern Link)

Tags: trailer, folding-bicycle

Is it possible to attach a kids trailer (a Thule Chariot) on a folding bike?

As I already have 2 bikes with a Weber hitch, I would prefer to use that on the folding bike as well. Currently, I want to buy a Tern eLink and I would like to mount a Weber hitch on it. Is this possible and if it is, can the bike still easily be folded? Can the magnet still be used to hold the folded bike together? I think the rear of the Tern eLink is identical to the Tern Link D7I, so if someone has any experience with that combination, it would be great if you could share it.

- Tern Link D7I: http://www.ternbicycles.com/de/bikes/472/elink
- Tern eLink: http://www.ternbicycles.com/de/bikes/472/elink
- Weber hitch: http://www.weber-products.de/products/kupplungen-ubersicht/

Comment: I don't know about your combination sorry, but I have a towball mounted on a generic 20" folder's rear axle okay.  Its a better tow tractor than a bigger bike due to gearing and it brakes better.